# Set focus to newly open window

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell, focus

I use Archlinux 3.17.2-1 with gnome-shell 3.14.1.5-1

I use keyboard shortcut to open various applications, for instance `Ctrl+Alt+G` opens `gnome-terminal` and `Ctrl+Alt+T` opens `xfce4-terminal`

When pressing `Ctrl+Alt+g`, the focus is set to the newly openned terminal but when pressing `Ctrl+Alt+t` the focus doesn't change to the opened terminal.

Is there any command that would make shure the focus is set to the new window ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a `wmctrl` call at the end of my `.zshrc` file

```
wmctrl -i -a $(wmctrl -l | grep Terminal | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

This forces the focus to the last openned windows with the name terminal

(I guess the grep Terminal could be removed)

Comment: Can you suggest why the following, which is called from my Openbox rc.xml file, as a keyboard shortcut does not work?  `gnome-terminal;
wmctrl -i -a $(wmctrl -l | grep arch@t430 | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)` The first gnome terminal opened comes to focus but not gnome terminal's opened after the first one has been opened & minimised. ps the grep term as you say can be redundant but does find the correct entry at the tail end of the list

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I had this new xfce4 terminal installed which annoyingly was opening without focus in place. That fix is exactly what I needed.